# How to improve resursive function performance?

Tags: java, selenium

I created a recursive function. The goal of this function is to browse all frames til to find the element. But it is very slow.

Please find below the function:

```
private WebElement browseFramesToFindElement(By locator) {
    WebElement element = null;
    if (isElementPresent(locator, 1))
        element = this.driver.findElement(locator);

    if (element == null) {
        List<WebElement> frames = this.driver.findElements(By.xpath("//frame"));
        int i = 0;
        while (i < frames.size() && element == null) {
            this.driver.switchTo().frame(this.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//frame[@id = '" + frames.get(i).getAttribute("id") + "']")));
            element = browseFramesToFindElement(locator);
            if (element == null)
                driver.switchTo().parentFrame();
            i++;
        }
    }
    return element;
}

private boolean isElementPresent(By by, int secToWait) {  
    this.driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(secToWait, TimeUnit.SECONDS);  
    try {  
        this.driver.findElement(by);  
        return true;  
    } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {  
        return false;
    }
}
```

Could you please tell me if it is possible to improve performance? And How? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why do you think the performance should be improved?

Comment: Because it is slow. Sometimes, it takes several minutes to find the element.

Comment: Does it have to be recursive? Java is not a natural fit for recursion as the more method calls you make the slower things will get. (plus the chance of blowing the stack) I would recommend rewriting it non-recursively.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. In my case I have nested frames so without recursivity I don't know how to do exactly to be honest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure your performance issues are related with that you have ineffective recursion algorithm. I would suggest you to:

- Change xpath locators to css locators (likely will help)
- Tune wait timeouts and watch for the result (not sure but that might give a direction)

Comment: Thank you. I will try to find better xpath as locator but use css locators is not possible in my case...

Comment: Why is it not possible?

Comment: It is possible sorry, but it will be complex because I need to use xpath functions like normalize-space. But if CSS Locators are faster XPATH then ...

Comment: Start from using css where you lookup frames at least

Comment: Thank you it is faster! I will try to convert maximum of locator with css locator.